# Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was sent to a service expecting text/xml; charset=utf-8

Tags: c#, wcf

Hi I am experiencing with an error when retrieving Data From WCF service.
Error as Follows.

Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was sent to a service expecting text/xml; charset=utf-8.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.

Here is my WCF web.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>



  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
      switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
      propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traceListener"
          type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
          initializeData= "c:\log\Traces1.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="2147483647" />

  </system.web>


               <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>

  <runtime>

    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">

      <dependentAssembly>



      </dependentAssembly>

    </assemblyBinding>

  </runtime>


</configuration>
```

And This is Client app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IKluiChatService" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:45022/KluiChatService.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IKluiChatService"
                contract="ServiceReference1.IKluiChatService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IKluiChatService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>

  <runtime xmlns="">
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

And This is IService.cs

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{



    [OperationContract]
    Fullresponse GetAllContacts(string id, string skey);
}
```

This is Service.svc

```
public class Service : IService
    {



       public Fullresponse GetAllContacts(string id, string skey)
        {
            Fullresponse fr = new Fullresponse();
            SearchContacts sr = new SearchContacts();
            fr = sr.GetJson(id, skey);
            return fr;
        }
    }
```

Here are the Data Retrieving Functions

```
public Fullresponse GetJson(string id, string skey)
        {
            string query = "";
            RootObject root = new RootObject();
            Query newquery = new Query();
            Facets newfacet = new Facets();

            if (id == "")
            {
                MatchAll Match = new MatchAll();
                newquery.match_all = Match;
                root.query = newquery;
                root.from = 0;
                root.size = 500000;
                root.sort = new List<string> ();
                root.sort.Add("categoryName");
                root.facets = newfacet;
                query = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
               //  = @"{ ""query"" : {  ""match_all"" : {} }  ,""from"":0,""size"":50,""sort"":[""categoryName""],""facets"":{}}";
            }
            else
            {
                Wildcard Wild = new Wildcard();
                Wild.title = "*" + id + "*";
                newquery.wildcard = Wild;
                root.query = newquery;
                root.from = 0;
                root.size = 500000;
                root.sort = new List<string>();
                root.sort.Add("categoryName");
                root.facets = newfacet;
                query = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
               // query = @"{    |query| : { |wildcard| : {|title|:|*" + id + @"*|}    }    ,|from|:0,|size|:50,|sort|:[|categoryName|],|facets|:{}}";
               // query = query.Replace("|", @"""");
            }
            Tuple<JObject> tuple = GetTuple(query);
            Fullresponse Json = Search(tuple.Item1, id, skey); //obtaining searched objects
            var s = JsonSerializer.Create();
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            using (var sw = new StringWriter(sb))
            {
                s.Serialize(sw, Json);
            }
            return Json;

        }

        //Elastic Search
        public Tuple<JObject> GetTuple(string query)

        {
            var node = new Uri(DAL_Common.Config.GetConfiguration("ElasticSearchIndex"));
            var config = new ConnectionSettings(node, defaultIndex: "kluitttnew");
            var client = new ElasticsearchClient(config);

            var result = client.Search<string>(query);

            var res = result.Response;
            JObject results = JObject.Parse(res);
            var hits = results["hits"].ToString();
            JObject wohits = JObject.Parse(hits);



          /*  var categories =
                      from c in results["hits"]["hits"].Children()["_source"]["categoryName"].Values()
                      group c by c
                          into g
                          orderby g.Count() descending
                          select new { Category = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };

            int catCount = 0;
            if (categories != null && categories.Count() > 0)
            {
                catCount = categories.Count();
            }*/
            return Tuple.Create(wohits);
        }
        protected Fullresponse Search(JObject wohits, string id, string skey)
        {

            List<Results> AllResults = new List<Results>();
            List<Object> on = new List<Object>();
            List<Object> off = new List<Object>();
            List<string> SubIDS = new List<string>();
            Results Online = new Results();
            Results Offline = new Results();
            categoryCollection categoryCollection;
            Fullresponse Fullresponse = new Fullresponse();
            int raws = 0;
            int catCount = 0;
            foreach (var item in wohits["hits"])
            {
                JToken srce = item["_source"];
                JObject source = JObject.Parse(item["_source"].ToString());
                if (((source["tofrom"].ToString()).ToLower() == "newtoall" || (source["tofrom"].ToString()).Contains(skey.ToString())) && source["SubID"].ToString() != skey.ToString())
                {


                if ((source["categoryName"].ToString()).ToLower() == "online")
                {
                    raws++;


                    on.Add(new Contact(source["title"].ToString(), StringCipher.Encrypt(source["url"].ToString()), source["description"].ToString(), id));
                    SubIDS.Add(source["SubID"].ToString());
                }

                if ((source["categoryName"].ToString()).ToLower() == "offline")
                {

                    off.Add(new Contact(source["title"].ToString(), StringCipher.Encrypt(source["url"].ToString()), source["description"].ToString(), id));
                    SubIDS.Add(source["SubID"].ToString());

                }
                }

            }

            foreach (var item in wohits["hits"])
            {
                JToken srce = item["_source"];
                JObject source = JObject.Parse(item["_source"].ToString());
                if ((source["tofrom"].ToString()).ToLower() != "newtoall" && !(source["tofrom"].ToString()).Contains(skey.ToString()))
                {

                    bool value = SubIDS.Exists(i => i == source["SubID"].ToString());
                    if (!value)
                    {
                        if ((source["categoryName"].ToString()).ToLower() == "online")
                        {
                            raws++;


                            on.Add(new Contact(source["title"].ToString(), StringCipher.Encrypt("new-" + source["SubID"].ToString()), source["description"].ToString(), id));
                            SubIDS.Add(source["SubID"].ToString());
                        }

                        if ((source["categoryName"].ToString()).ToLower() == "offline")
                        {

                            off.Add(new Contact(source["title"].ToString(), StringCipher.Encrypt("new-" + source["SubID"].ToString()), source["description"].ToString(), id));
                            SubIDS.Add(source["SubID"].ToString());

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (on.Count > 0)
            {
                Online.categoryName="Online";
                Online.results=on;
                catCount++;
            }
             if (off.Count > 0)
            {
                Offline.categoryName="Offline";
                Offline.results=off;
                catCount++;
            }
             if (catCount>1)
             {
                 categoryCollection = new categoryCollection ();
                 categoryCollection.online = Online;
                 categoryCollection.offline = Offline;
             }
             else
             {
                 if (on.Count > 0 && off.Count ==0)
                 {
                     categoryCollection = new categoryCollection();
                     categoryCollection.online = Online;
                 }
                 else if (on.Count == 0 && off.Count > 0)
                 {
                     categoryCollection = new categoryCollection();
                     categoryCollection.offline = Offline;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     categoryCollection = new categoryCollection();

                 }
             }
             Fullresponse.success = "true";
             Fullresponse.term = id;
             Fullresponse.categories = categoryCollection;
             Fullresponse.total = catCount.ToString();

            return Fullresponse;
        }
```

here is my Fullresponse class

```
[DataContract]
     public class Fullresponse
        {
             [DataMember]
            public string success { get; set; }
             [DataMember]
            public string participants { get; set; }
             [DataMember]
            public string term { get; set; }
             [DataMember]
            public categoryCollection categories { get; set; }

             [DataMember]
            public string total { get; set; }

             [DataMember]
            public Contact[] contacts { get; set; }

             [DataMember]
            public ChatMessage message { get; set; }

             [DataMember]
            public ChatMessage[] messages { get; set; }

        }
```

Client Side Code

```
ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();

            Fullresponse res = client.GetAllContacts("","");
```

In my Fullresponse class i am using categoryCollection class object as [Datamember]. when i comment this object addition in Fullresponse creation it works fine. Here are my Other Classes.

```
 [DataContract]
    public class categoryCollection
    {
        [DataMember]
        public Results online { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public Results offline { get; set; }
    }

 public class Results
    {
        public string categoryName { get; set; }


        public List<Object> results { get; set; }
    }
```

Please Help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Is your apppool set to .net 4.5?

Comment: Actually I am using console application running as client and service is add as service reference to this console app. All two in same solution.

Comment: Show us the code for `Fullresponse` and client side code. what's the use of  `fr = sr.GetJson(id, skey);` ?

Comment: i have added the rest code...

Comment: You still have not added the code for `Fullresponse`.

Comment: Just Added Fullresponse Class

Comment: Comment `\\SearchContacts sr = new SearchContacts();
            \\fr = sr.GetJson(id, skey);` and run the service. Then see what happens.

Comment: No exceptions.. running smoothly.. return a empty object

Comment: That means the bug is in your `GetJson` method. So put a break point and debug.

Comment: I just add Other classess which i am using. In my Fullresponse class i am using categoryCollection class object as [Datamember]. when i comment this object addition in Fullresponse creation it works fine.